# Inserting data into gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have database in my sql server. On my webpage, i have created a table (gridview). Instead creating a form (txtbox), I would prefer user entering their data in the table.

Here is my VB code of my gridview:

```
  Private Sub LoadGridStaff()
        Dim q As String

        For r = 0 To gvTable.Rows.Count - 1
            q = "INSERT INTO staff_OT (Staff_no, Staff_name, OverTime, PayCode)" & _
                "values('" & gvTable.Rows.Cells(0).Value & " ', ' " & gvTable.Rows.Cells(1).Value & "','" & gvTrans.Rows.Cells(2).Value & " ', '" & gvTrans.Rows.Cells(3).Value & " ')"

        Next

    End Sub
```

---

And the error is :

> Cells' is not a member of 'System.Web.Ui.WebControls.GridviewRowCollection'

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate the index of the `RowCollection` with the iteration variable of the loop.

```
Private Sub LoadGridStaff()
    Dim q As String
    For r = 0 To gvTable.Rows.Count - 1
        q = "INSERT INTO staff_OT (Staff_no, Staff_name, OverTime, PayCode)" & _
            "values('" & gvTable.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value & " ', ' " & gvTable.Rows(r).Cells(1).Value & "','" & gvTrans.Rows(r).Cells(2).Value & " ', '" & gvTrans.Rows(r).Cells(3).Value & " ')"
    'do db work
    Next
End Sub
```